# Should I declare JavaScript variables and then initialize right after?

Tags: javascript

Im new to JavaScript and I was wondering if declaring variables and then initializing right after declaration is a best practice. For example:

```
var x = 5 ;
var y = 6 ;
```

Instead of:

```
var x , y ;

x = 5;
y = 6 ;
```

Comment: It depends on your use case of those variables.

Comment: It really doesn't matter in JS. As long as you initialize them before referencing them.

Comment: *"initializing right after declaration is a best practice"*. No, it's not. If you know the value of the variable it's better to declare and initialize it at once.

Comment: So just to be safe declare and initialize right after declaration?

Comment: don't matter. But if you know what value you want to initialize do it right after declaration to be on safer side.

Comment: go with `var x = 5,  y = 6 ;` or listen to 1,001 other opinions that don't affect execution.

Comment: Just make sure you have some basic understanding of **Javascript scoping and hoisting** - http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How this is done does not affect execution in any way, and is merely a question regarding readability.

If it has your preference to declare, then assign separately, by all means do so.

If you are *not* using local scope variables like `var banana`, like in classes, there is some effect on execution (but barely).

example : 
this is probably easier to read, (but that is a personal opinion) and requires less operations

```
var Foo = Class.reate();
Foo.prototype = {
    hoge : 1,
    fuga : 2,
    initialize : function(){
    }
};
```

than this :

```
var Foo = Class.reate();
Foo.prototype = {
    hoge:null,
    fuga:null,
    initialize : function(){
        this.hoge = 1;
        this.fuga = 2;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok answer but I wouldn't bring in "classes" (functions moonlighting as classical inheritance) since it's bound to  to confuse a beginner.

Comment: @papirtiger i agree they might be confusing to beginners, but since they are an area where there is actual difference in operations when using variables as properties, i figured that for brevety's sake, it would be good to include it.

Answer (score 4):

How you actually declare variables is a matter of preference.
If you declare multiple variables after each other you can omit the `var` keyword and instead use commas to "continue" the statement.

```
var x = 2,
    y = 3;
```

If I am using one variable in the assignment of another I like to split the declaration and assignment for readability.

```
var x = 2,
    y = x + 3;
```

## vs

```
var x, y;
x = 2;
y = x + 3;
```

Again this is only a preference since any variable in javascript is usable as soon as it is declared

- even in the same `var` statement.

Its important to remember that variables in javascript have function scope - not block scope as commonly encountered in other languages.

```js
(function(){
  var x = 1;
    
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    var x = i;
  }
    
  (function(){
    var x = 999;
  }());

  alert(x); // 9!
}());
```

The javascript guru [Douglas Crockford recommends](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) that variable definitions be listed at the top of each function to make this extra apparent to programmers used to languages with proper block scope.

**Update:**

The use of `var` is not recommended in modern javascript. `let` and `const` are supported by all modern browsers and they have true block scope and are not hoisted to the top of a function.